# Excel 2011 for Mac/ Pivot table / tabular layout how to "fill down?"

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table, microsoft-excel-2011

I've got a great pivot table in tabular layout, but how do I "fill down" values in column A?

[image]

A10 should also read "Alpaha Police"

A15:A18 should also read "Atkinson Co Sheriff"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Excel 2010 for Windows (and later) the Pivot Table Design ribbon contains a drop-down called "Report Layout". Selecting "Tabular Layout" and "Repeat all item labels" will show a tabular layout with no blank cells.

Unfortunately, this setting is not available in Excel 2011 for Mac. You may need to copy the pivot table and use formulas to fill in the blanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've been unable to do this in (mac) excel 2011 but I just took a file created in 2011, turned on this option in 2016 (option does exist in mac office 2016) and then re-opened file in 2011. The setting stuck thru data refreshes and minor table changes such as adding additional fields in the "Values" section.  Other than that, though, I've got no idea how sticky the setting is.  Sadly just another example of how mac:office 2011 was not fully implemented.

Option 2:
Run some version of this code - it appears that once you set the "repeat titles" that is sticks, so you can run code then delete code module (credit to dailydoseofexcel.com for this code)

```
Sub PivotGrid()

Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim pf As PivotField

On Error Resume Next
    Set pt = ActiveCell.PivotTable
On Error GoTo 0

If Not pt Is Nothing Then
    With pt
        .InGridDropZones = True
        .RowAxisLayout xlTabularRow
    End With

    For Each pf In pt.PivotFields
        If pf.Orientation = xlRowField Then
            pf.Subtotals = Array(False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False)
            pf.RepeatLabels = True
        End If
    Next pf
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution exist since Excel 2010. When pivot is active, under Pivotable Tools,go to Design on the ribbon,select Report layout,Repeat all items labels. Done!